# command opam update fail

Tags: ocaml, opam

On my system, ArchLinux x86_64, I have installed the package opam-git which was working the last time I used it.

The following command `opam update` fail with this message:

```
opam update

=-=- Updating package repositories =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[ERROR] curl: code 404 while downloading https://opam.ocaml.org/1.3/urls.txt
[ERROR] Could not update repository default
```

In this link https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/6231 they say:

> it is 2.0.dev now

What should I do to resolve my problem?

Comment: Retry when the patch is merged?

Comment: Seriously? I can not install any packages or make any updates.

Comment: This is a git devel version of opam, did I get this right? Current release is 1.2. Your 1.3 changed, so pull the new revision and rebuild opam. Or will Arch have to do it?

Comment: It is an AUR package. So the idea is to reinstall opam? You should answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a git devel version of opam, did I get this right? Current opam release is 1.2.

And it is from Arch AUR?

It looks like AUR published an inconsistent opam dev state from git.

Once the git is consistent (pull request done) file a bug report, wait for the update, and do a new opam install from AUR.

Or just rely on the current versions from ocaml.org, IMO the premier source.

BTW when encountering problems with your local .opam directory and the compiled ocaml packages: the whole stuff can be deleted and reinstalled without any side effects (provided your own source is somewhere else). This is the functional paradigm.

/Str.